# Unable to pass all test cases in online judge

Tags: java, string, algorithm

My solution is not accepted by the online judge. Any help would be appreciated.

[JP and Strings](https://www.codechef.com/problems/PEC004)

> A 1-character string is which consists of only one letter 'a',
>   2-character string consists of only letters 'a' and 'b'. Similarly
>   26-character string consists of all the small letters in alphabet i.e
>   from 'a' to 'z'.  A string is valid if there is no character in the
>   string which has the same position as in the alphabetical sequence.
>   For example, string "bac" is not valid because the character 'c' is at
>   the position 3 in the string(Consider string and alphabets both as
>   1-indexed) which is same as in the alphabetical sequence. Whereas
>   string "cab" is valid. Now there is a function F(N , L) such that,
>
> F(N , L) = Number of valid N-Character strings of length L.
>
> Input: The first line will contain the number of queries Q. Next Q
>   lines will contain two space separated integers containing N and L.
>
> Output: For every query print a single line containing the value of
>   the function F(N , L). Answer may be too large so print it modulo
>   1000000007.
>
> Constraints: 1 <= Q <= 10^3 1 <= N <= 26 1 <= L <= 10^9
>
> Statement: Given two integers N and L where N represents the number of
>   characters and L represents the length of string.

### My solution approach is:

There will be two possible use cases:

1.) L <= N If length of string L is less or equal to N then at each position we can choose N-1 characters so total number of strings will be (N-1)^L

2.) L > N If length of string L is grater than N then number of possible strings will be: (N-1)^N * N^(L-N) For rest N position we can choose N-1 characters but after Nth position all N characters can be used.

Code: http://ideone.com/fzGLKH

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    FastScanner in = new FastScanner();
    int q = in.nextInt();
    int n,l;
    while(q>0){
        n = in.nextInt();
        l = in.nextInt();
        if(n<l){
            System.out.println((int)((Math.pow(n-1, n)*Math.pow(n, l-n))% 1000000007));
        }
        else{
            System.out.println((int)(Math.pow(n-1, l)% 1000000007));
        }
        q--;
    }

}
```

Comment: Use `BigInteger` to calculate the value and then do the modulo

Comment: The error is quite likely due to `Math.pow`. `double` is imprecise. And the cast to `int` might cut away digits from the result or switch the sign, which as well would produce incorrect results. Instead use `a * b mod c = ((a mod c) * (b mod c)) mod c or `BigInteger` to calculate the appropriate results.

Comment: @Paul Actually, the constraints is 1 <= L <= 1000000000, so you can't use BigInteger or you will cause TLE or MLE because of digits.

Comment: @square1001 didn't notice that constraint. Then applying modulo a few times is the way to go. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What's the bug?

You are doing `Math.pow(n - 1, l) % 1000000007`.

The problem's constraints is `1 <= l <= 1000000000`, so it may be a huge value like 10^9-digit number. It will cause overflow and you cannot get correct answer.

#### The solution for the bug

What do you do if you want to calculate `a^b mod m (a^b is the bth power of a)`.
You can use [Exponentation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) algorithm for calculating `a^b mod m`.
The algorithm in java is following:

```
public static long modpow(long a, long b, long m) {
    long ret = 1;
    while(b > 0) {
        if((b & 1) == 1) ret = ret * a % m;
        a = a * a % m;
        b >>= 1;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

The time complexity is `O(log b)`, so you can solve this problem!